# ASP.NET: Using the right click to trigger an <input type=file> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

What I'm trying to do is use the `contextmenu()` to trigger the input of `type="file"`

When simply trying it out as `.html` file it works perfectly normal:

```
<input type="file" id="File1" class="file2" runat="Server" accept="image/*">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").contextmenu(function () {
            alert("right click!!");
            document.getElementById('File1').click();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I try to do the exact same thing in my asp.net project, it does not "click" the button:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TESTER.aspx.cs" Inherits="CustomTemplates.TESTER" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<input type="file" id="File1" class="file2" runat="Server" accept="image/*">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").contextmenu(function () {
            alert("right click!!");
            document.getElementById('MainContent_File1').click();
            return false;
        });
   });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

although the alert does get shown.  (Also I made sure the ID of the input is correct from the console)

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Oh ye, Its included in the project.

Comment: Sorry - that was a dumb question.  You wouldn't get the alert at all if you hadn't included jQuery.  What happens if you execute `document.getElementById('MainContent_File1').click()` in the console?

Comment: I just tried it, It works normally if I execute it from the browser console... I don't understand the problem at all :/

Comment: You could try executing the postback method manually.  Instead of triggering a click, try `__doPostBack('MainContent_File1','OnClick');`  (Note the 2 x `_`, not just 1)

Comment: The problem remains :'(

Comment: Is the input visible?

Comment: Yes it is visible.

Comment: There must be something else going on.  I've duplicated what you've got and it works fine.  Something else, not included here, is causing your problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time :) I will look into it.

Comment: No worries - good luck :)